# First time push view controller taking too much time when calling swift code from objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, time, navigation

1. I am  pushing a view controller written in Swift from view controller in ObjC , now the problem is there is too much lag between clicking and reaching control to `viewDidLoad` of Swift class.
2. I am doing nothing in `viewWillAppear` of Swift class and `ViewDidDisappear` of ObjectiveC class (previous class)
3. Most Important thing is that this lag appears only first time after I launch the app
4. I am using `SwiftyJSON` in my project

Comment: Did you check with background thread? add some code u tried

Comment: What do you do in `viewDidLoad` or in `prepareFor(segue)`?  It sounds like you may be performing some synchronous load operation somewhere.  Use the Time Profiler instrument to identify the problem

Comment: I had a problem like yours in the past and it was a another operation that was causing the issue, loading some synchronous data, it almost dive me crazy

Comment: if you show the code, it would be a hole lot easier for everybody to help out...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the animated effect to NO.

```
SwiftClassViewController *swiftVC = [[SwiftClassViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```